# Why is this lambda operation not working?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I want to take any values in my dataframe that are shown as 'less than' and report them as numbers half of the less-than value.

e.g. <1 becomes 0.5,  <0.5 becomes 0.25, <5 becomes 2.5  etc.
ordinary numbers and text should be unchanged.

I have the following lambda function to apply to my dataframe that I thought was working but it isn't:

```py
df_no_less_thans= df.apply(lambda x: x if str(x[0])!='<' else float(x[1:])/2)
```

I am still getting '<' values in the new df, no error messages.

What have I done wrong?

```py
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Cu']=[3.7612,1.3693, 2.7502,1.407,4.2066,6.4409,6.8136,"<0.05","<0.05",0.94,0.07,1.82,2.63,1.36,0.78]
df.apply(lambda x: x if str(x)[0]!='<' else float(str(x)[1:])/2) 
df
```

gives

````
    Cu
0   3.7612
1   1.3693
2   2.7502
3   1.407
4   4.2066
5   6.4409
6   6.8136
7   <0.05
8   <0.05
9   0.94
10  0.07
11  1.82
12  2.63
13  1.36
14  0.7 ```
````

Comment: I applied this lambda on a bare list `li = ['<1', '<0.5', '<5']` and it gives me the expected output `[0.5, 0.25, 2.5]`

Comment: Tested and working nice... `df = pd.Series(['<1','<0.5','<5'])`

Comment: Show some example input which this fails. And the failed output.

Comment: @ruohola done as requested

Comment: This seems like a horrible dataframe layout, mixing strings and floats in one column...

Comment: You need to apply element-wise, e.g. `df.applymap(...)` or `df['Cu'].apply(...)`.

Comment: @NilsWerner That's not a constructive comment Nils.  It is how a lot of environmental data is reported as instruments have a 'detection limit' so values below this are reported as "less than" values, as is not appropriate to say there is zero concentration.

Comment: @flashliquid in that case, it would be safer to either treat _all_ values as strings until the point of use (where you can check for the "less than" condition), or immediately convert to zero (or NaN).

Comment: @flashliquid just because the data is provided that way doesn't mean you are not allowed to transform it to something more useful. :-) Have a look at my answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `apply` has an `axis` argument. By default, `axis=0`, which means that your lambda function is applied successively to each column in the dataframe. In your case, the lambda function is applied to the column `'Cu'`, meaning that the argument `x` is actually a column and `str(x)[0]` is not what you think.

You should use `applymap` instead, to apply the lambda function element-wise:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x if str(x)[0] != '<' else float(str(x)[1:])/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work with non-strings like integers or floats since you cannot index them without converting them to a string. You can explicitly cast everything to string and perform your indexing

You would also want to have a check for empty strings before you perform the lambda operation

```
#Explicitly cast to string and perform the indexing
func = lambda x: x if  str(x)[0]!='<' else float(str(x)[1:])/2

li = ['<1', '<0.5', '<5', 1, 'hello', 4.0, '']

#Filter out empty strings
print([func(item) for item in li if item])
```

The output will be

```
[0.5, 0.25, 2.5, 1, 'hello', 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need apply lambda function only for `Cu` column, so correct solution is use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Cu'] = df['Cu'].apply(lambda x: x if str(x)[0]!='<' else float(str(x)[1:])/2) 
print (df)

        Cu
0   3.7612
1   1.3693
2   2.7502
3   1.4070
4   4.2066
5   6.4409
6   6.8136
7   0.0250
8   0.0250
9   0.9400
10  0.0700
11  1.8200
12  2.6300
13  1.3600
14  0.7800
```

If need apply function for all columns use [IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490265/2901002) solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say

> e.g. <1 becomes 0.5, <0.5 becomes 0.25, <5 becomes 2.5 etc. ordinary numbers and **text should be unchanged**.

Now in the example you have given you only have the first two types of data: strings like `<1` and `float`s, but you seem to want to be able to retain any kind of other text, too. However I see **mixing different dtypes in one column as a bad dataframe layout** that will only cause trouble in the future.

If, for example, you had some text `hello` in your column, a simple operation like:

```
df['Cu'] * 2
# [...]
# 6        13.6272
# 7     hellohello
# 8           0.05
# 9           1.88
# [...]
# Name: Cu, dtype: object
```

This is most likely not what you want.

Now I don't know what other kinds of text you have, but for the examples given I would recommend normalizing the dtypes first: For that we create a new column `df['less_than']` from the "uncertainty information":

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Cu']=[3.7612,1.3693, 2.7502,1.407,4.2066,6.4409,6.8136,"<0.05","<0.05",0.94,0.07,1.82,2.63,1.36,0.78]

df['less_than'] = df['Cu'].str.startswith('<', False)
df.loc[df['less_than'], 'Cu'] = df.loc[df['less_than'], 'Cu'].str.slice(1)

df['Cu'] = df['Cu'].astype(float)
#         Cu  less_than
# 0   3.7612      False
# 1   1.3693      False
# 2   2.7502      False
# 3   1.4070      False
# 4   4.2066      False
# 5   6.4409      False
# 6   6.8136      False
# 7   0.0500       True
# 8   0.0500       True
# 9   0.9400      False
# 10  0.0700      False
# 11  1.8200      False
# 12  2.6300      False
# 13  1.3600      False
# 14  0.7800      False
```

This enables us to do treat the entire column `df['Cu']` the same, and making your "<1 becomes 0.5" operations a simple one-liner:

```
df.loc[df['less_than'], 'Cu'] /= 2
```

Comment: This is not a scalable solution. My actual dataset is 35K rows and 150 columns. It's not feasible to manually calculate what half the detection limit is for each occurrence. Bad style doesn't come into it when the data is supplied as is for processing.  My question is about how to transform this data. Your feedback is like stopping for directions and being told  "Well I wouldn't start from here".  But thanks for the downvote Mr 19.7k rep.

Comment: What? I never downvoted anything. And I am fully accepting that you have to deal with heterogeneous data. My answer is simply: you should do this additional step so your data becomes more useful and easier to work with in the future. The code I provided is fully vectorized and is most likely the most performant of all the answers and the fact that you have 150 columns is just another technical problem but has nothing to do with the solution *per se*.

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood your question. I was under the impression that you wanted to keep your mixed `str`/`float` column `dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Cu']=[3.7612,1.3693, 2.7502,1.407,4.2066,6.4409,6.8136,"<0.05","<0.05",0.94,0.07,1.82,2.63,1.36,0.78]

df['Cu'] = df.apply(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x[0],str) else float(x[0][1:])/2, axis=1, raw=True)

print(df)
```

result:

```
        Cu
0   3.7612
1   1.3693
2   2.7502
3    1.407
4   4.2066
5   6.4409
6   6.8136
7    0.025
8    0.025
9     0.94
10    0.07
11    1.82
12    2.63
13    1.36
14    0.78
```